# Session not created Exception with cucumber scripts

Tags: selenium, cucumber

I keep getting the below error when i ran my selenium cucumber scripts. I have always run the script with chrome version 72 and suddenly had this problem and have tried to downgrade to lower versions with no luck and also upgraded to newest version 73 with no luck.

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.28 seconds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Probably you are using **WebDriverManager** which downloads browser binary automatically. Seems like its trying to download latest chromedriver binary which may not be compatible to your chrome browser installed version let say 72 (my guess). If so, in that case we have to tell WebDriverManager to download chromedriver binary which would be compatible to your browser version 72. For doing so, please take a reference of below line and do update your code.*

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().version("2.46").setup();
```

*Note - We have added version("2.46") that means WebDriverManager would find out this particular version only of chromedriver binary.*

*Let's know if this resolve your problem.*

Comment: @TheSociety Anything specific within the _question_ or _error stack trace_ to suspect usage of _WebDriverManager_?

Comment: Yes, problem statement left a clue of WebDriverManager being used because scripts have been running successfully on chrome browser version 72 and statement says suddenly this problem started to come (point to be noted). WebDriverManager looks for the latest version of chromedriver binary so probably it took latest one i.e. ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6 which is not compatible for chrome browser 72 rather 74. if person had not been using webdrivermanager, in that case, he would have downloaded and set path of chromedriver and it can not change itself suddenly as problem statement says.

Comment: As the counter question was from my side unless you mark me along with the `@` character as `@DebanjanB` I would have no clue you replied to my query. In these cases only OP gets notified. +1 for the explanation

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing information about process as I am new member of stackoverflow family

Comment: @DebanjanB, can you please help me to understand, person replied something saying,"Thanks its working..." But its not visible now. Not able to understand how it happened but want to say that reply would have been there and helping members of stackoverflow to understand person tried and responded back.

Comment: If you look at the _placeholder_ of the comment box it is mentioned to _Avoid comments like “+1” or “thanks”_ as these are considered as _noise_ as per StackOverflow community guidelines. So I have deleted them.

Comment: Thank you @DebanjanB for guiding me. I am sorry being new to family, I am understanding these protocols.

Answer (score 0):

WebDriverManager only helps you when you are using latest chrome version.then in this case WDM automatically download latest chrome driver binary into local cache.

Example : Chrome browser installed in local machine is 72, and if you are using WDM into your script to avoid hassle-free up-gradation to chrome driver latest version then WDM automatically download the latest chromedriver version i.e 74

by writing this,

> WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

But this will create incompatibility issue between chrome browser and chromedriver . both version is different.

IF you select the version of chromedriver as mentioned below then this will solved your issue.

> WebDriverManager.chromedriver().version("2.46").setup();

If i have to mentioned all this staff then why should i dont use JVM properties
System.setproperty("key","path");